# How to add fake data in my rails app model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where users can add a link and others can like and dislike that link (or Posts).I want to add some fake likes and dislike to some links or post, I am really new to it and I don't know how to do this, I know it would be something very easy, I thought of `Faker Gem` , but It is not what I wanted.

Comment: You can seed to fill your db. You can write some ruby in "db/seed.rb"  and launch in your terminal 'rails db:seed'.

Comment: Show your `Post` class attributes

Answer (score 0):

Open the `db/seeds.rb` file and try something like this. I don't know your attributes but it should work if you replace the correct key and value in the `{}`.

```
Post.create!([{title: "Como", dislike: true}, {title: "llamas", like: true }])

p "Created #{Post.count} posts"
```

To execute:

```
rake db:seed
```